# Why does current not decrease in/after a resistor if electrons are impeded/lose energy?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, conservation-laws, electrical-resistance, conductors

I was told that current is uniform across a series circuit. Yet I was also told that a resistor works by impeding the flow of free electrons, which should mean slowing them down. Does this mean that the current drops while **inside** the resistor, but in-between resistors it is identical (and the speed on the whole is averaged, perhaps)? I don't understand how the resistor works, otherwise.

Also, it seems like electrons do not behave as expected when they lose electrical potential. When a particle loses energy, generally, it moves slower. A resistor causes more collisions, and with each collision some electrical potential is lost in the form of heat (maybe I'm wrong about this, but the electrical potential is lower after a resistor, so each coulomb has less energy). Why does this loss of energy not result in reduced current?

Ohm's Law suggests a similar conclusion, at least to me. If the conducting medium, let's say a copper wire, is identical throughout the circuit, then its resistance would be constant. Then $V=RI$ would dictate that I would go down as $V$ goes down. This is basically what I was saying above, but using an equation. If this is not true, then the change in voltage decreases the resistance, but I thought resistance was a property of the conducting medium, which does not change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the current remain the same in a circuit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529224/)

Comment: If you roll *N* bowling balls down a (bumpy) hill, they lose energy as they roll...but you still get all *N* bowling balls at the bottom of the hill and not just some of them.

Comment: If one part of the hill were smooth, and another was bumpy, the velocity of the bowling ball would be greater on the smooth part, and slower on the bumpy part. That's more what I'm asking, I think? Current isn't just a measure of quantity (that's Q, so far as I understand), but quantity per second (Q/t), so the speed matters.

Comment: @rde if you continuously released *N* balls per second at the top of the hill you would (after some time to allow steady state to be achieved) continuously receive *N* balls per second at the bottom of the hill. If you didn't, it would mean that somewhere on the hill bowling balls are piling up limitlessly. (Which is even harder to make happen with electrons than with bowlling balls because electrons repel each other and bowling balls don't)

Comment: Yes, it's the time between first release and steady state that was bothering me. I'm looking at a circuit that has a battery that would blow an LED unless a resistor is added. But it doesn't matter if the resistor is put before the LED (between the LED and the battery) or after the LED, apparently. This is initially confusing, because the first flow of overpowered current would flow through the light bulb. Wouldn't it make more sense to put the resistor first? But I gather that the current is slowed leaving the resistor, which slows the electrons leaving the battery... =slower steady state.

Comment: So, when the current first flows through a circuit with a light bulb, passing thru the light bulb does slow down the current... but that slows down the rate of return of electrons to the cathode, and that in turn slows down the exit of electrons from the anode? Which means that the current in a circuit with a light bulb is lower than the same circuit (same battery) without a light bulb. Before steady state, there is an initial disparity pre-/post-lightbulb in current rate, but this gets compensated for back at the battery, until current is constant across the circuit. Is that is, basically?

Comment: @rde In circuit theory, which is the model that works well for LED circuits, the current flows through the whole circuit simultaneously. It doesn't start from one end of the battery and go to the other. In the more sophisticated electromagnetic theory, the energy doesn't flow in the wire at all: the wire circuit guides a flow of energy through the space between the battery and the LED.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand electric circuits, forget electrons. Really. They are a distraction. Ohm never heard of an electron. When you get to electronic devices, then it's useful to consider what the electrons are doing, but not until then. Just use current.

But, if you must...

You're thinking that electrons move ballistically through the the wire, but they don't. They creep at whatever speed they need to have to support the current flow. If the medium has more resistivity, but you keep the current density constant, the electric field must increase to keep that speed.

Translating from densities and fields to the characteristics of "lumped" circuits, that leads to Ohm's law, $V=IR$.

And yes, as the current goes down, the voltage *drop* from one end of the wire goes down. In textbook circuits we usually neglect this, assuming the resistance of the wire is so low that the drop is effectively zero. In a real circuit, you may need to select the wire gauge according to the tolerable drop. But usually, the important voltage drops are elsewhere in the circuit, not in the wires.

Comment: 'but you keep the current density constant'. I'm asking about why the current remains constant, but this seems to take for granted that it does. Otherwise, I vaguely understand drift, as in the electrons do not move efficiently in one direction, even when a current is influencing them, but instead move semi-randomly or chaotically. But the drift speed would be slowed down more by more impediments, no?

Comment: @rde Ohm's law. Hold voltage constant, increase resistance, current decreases. Hold current constant, increase resistance, voltage increases.